# Javascript Timeline Visualisation

Tags: java, javascript, google-app-engine, charts

I am planning to collect some data on the execution of requests within a Java Tomcat container. Each request is fulfilled by data retreived by multiple threads and I want to display this execution with a graphic similar to the Google App Engine App Stats tool:

[image: AppStats screenshot]

Can anyone suggest a javascript library for drawing this kind of chart? I'm not even sure what the proper name would be for this. Searching for timelines turns up things like http://timeglider.com/jquery/ which seems to do something different.

Comment: Do you really need a javascript library? They're just a bunch of rectangular, colored DIVs absolutely positioned in a container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a simple timeline with overlapping bars like in a [bullet chart](http://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/misc/Bullet_Graph_Design_Spec.pdf). You can see one example here in [Protovis](http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/bullet.html). If you know a bit of javascript, you can program one in [D3.js](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/), the successor of Protovis. There is a [complete example](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/1b1a9485cb8204c0dc3eb5576479884271832136/examples/bullet/bullet.html) in the demos that come with the download.